# Demonstrate using first-order conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

A quadratic function of the form function $ f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ , given by $ f(x)=(1/2)x^T P x + q^T x + r$, where $P\succeq 0$ and $x, q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r \in\mathbb{R}$. How can I demonstrate that it is convex using first-order conditions?

My attempt:

In S.Boyd's lecture:

1. First-order: f is convex if $f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)$

Then,

$$
f(y)\geq (1/2)x^T P x + q^T x + r+ (Px+q)^T(y-x)
$$

How do I simplify? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a transpose in the $Px+q$ term. If write out the left-hand side $f(y)$ in terms of $P,q,r,y$ and combine terms, something may emerge.

Comment: Thank you! @angryavian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(y) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)(y-x) &= \frac12 y^TPy + q^Ty + r - \left(\frac12 x^TPx + q^Tx + r\right) - \left(Px + q\right)^T(y-x)\\
&= \frac12y^TPy  + q^Ty + r - \frac12x^TPx - q^Tx - r - x^TPy + x^TPx - q^Ty + q^Tx\\
&= \frac12\left(y^TPy - 2x^TPy + x^TPx\right)\\
&= \frac12 (y-x)^TP(y-x)\ge 0
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! @Youem

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
f(y) &\ge f(x) + \nabla f(x)^\top (y-x)
\\
\frac{1}{2} y^\top P y + q^\top y + r
&\ge \frac{1}{2} x^\top P x + q^\top x + r + (Px+q)^\top (y-x).
\end{align}

If you cancel terms and rearrange, you will eventually get $(y-x)^\top P (y-x) \ge 0$ which you can justify using a given property of $P$.